# Is it possible to create a DataGridTemplateColumn that can switch (dynamically) on row level between checkbox and textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, wpftoolkit

Is it possible to create a DataGridColumn that can contain both TextBlock and Checkbox. Let's say for example that I have defined a Datagrid with 7 Columns one of which is a DataGridCheckBoxColumn on the dataGrid and the others have TextBlocks. Then when I check the checkbox in a row I want all the cells on that row from TextBlocks to become Checkboxes while the rest rows remain unaffected (I am using VS2008).

Answer (score 0):

You could expose a property on your bound object and link everything accordingly:

```
Property ---+<---> CheckBoxCol
            |
            +----> TemplateCol >> Trigger ----- TextBlock
                                     |
                                     +--------- CheckBox
```

So the Checkbox in one column affects said property and the templates of the other columns contain `DataTriggers` which check is the property is true or false and show the according content.